# An example of a unique value function which is associated with multiple optimal policies

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policies, value-functions, optimal-policy

In the 4th paragraph of 
http://www.incompleteideas.net/book/ebook/node37.html
it is mentioned:

> Whereas the optimal value functions for states and state-action pairs are unique for a given MDP, there can be many optimal policies

Could you please give me a simple example that shows different optimal policies considering a unique value function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a very simple grid-world, consisting of 4 cells, where an agent starts in the bottom-left corner, has actions to move North/East/South/West, and receives a reward $R = 1$ for reaching the top-right corner, which is a terminal state. We'll name the four cells $NW$, $NE$, $SW$ and $SE$ (for north-west, north-east, south-west and south-east). We'll take a discount factor $\gamma = 0.9$.

The initial position is $SW$, and the goal is $NE$, which an optimal policy should reach as quickly as possible. However, there are two optimal policies for the starting state $SW$: we can either go north first, and then east (i.e., $SW \rightarrow NW \rightarrow NE$), or we can go east first, and then north (i.e., $SW \rightarrow SE \rightarrow NE$). Both of those policies are optimal, both reach the goal state in two steps and receive a return of $\gamma \times 1 = 0.9$, but they are clearly different policies, they choose different actions in for the initial state.

Note that my language was *slightly* informal above when talking about "policies for the starting state". Formally, I should have said that there are two optimal policies that select different actions in the starting state (and the same actions in all other states).